# Why is my igraph multilevel community modularity None?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, igraph, membership, modularity

I created communities in igraph using:

```
 g = Graph.TupleList(tupleMapping)
 layout = g.layout("rt")
 comm = g.community_multilevel()
```

But how can I access these cluster levels? I can print the communities but I want to access the different clustering levels.

I tried print modularity using:

```
print comm._modularity
```

But my console returns null. Do you know why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`community_multilevel()` returns the optimal level (i.e. the one with the highest modularity) only. If you need to access all the levels, read the [API docs of `community_multilevel()`](http://pythonhosted.org/python-igraph/igraph.Graph-class.html#community_multilevel) and use the `return_levels=True` keyword argument; this will give you a list with all the levels.

> I tried print modularity using [...] But my console returns null. Do you know why?

Yes. You are accessing a private API that you are not supposed to access. You should use the `modularity` property, not `_modularity`. Modularity is calculated and cached in the private `_modularity` variable the first time you actually try to access the `modularity` property. Since you are bypassing this mechanism by reading `_modularity` directly, igraph will not calculate the modularity first.